# Generate a linux shell command with php that contains the "tab" character

Tags: php, linux, shell, shell-exec

I have to call a shell command with PHP. Therefore I use shell_exec().
That works fine for me. 
But now I have to pass two parameters that have to be separated by the TAB character. 
I tried to use `\t` but that won't work at all.
How can I make this work?

I want to call aria2c and have to seperate two or more URIs by the TAB character. I tried the following piece of code:

```
aria2c --ftp-user username --ftp-passwd pwd -c -p -t 100 -s 2 --max-connection-per-server 2 --max-download-limit=0 --allow-overwrite=true --file-allocation none --summary-interval 0 ftp://server/xxx ftp://server/xxx -o files/xxx files/xxx
```

URI `ftp://server/xxx ftp://server/xxx` has to be something like this: `ftp://server/xxx\tftp://server/xxx`

Comment: This depends on the shell-command you like to use. E.g. if it is echo-shell-command, you may use \t like the following `shell_exec('echo -e "foo\tbar" ');`
Be sure to pass \t as text to the echo here. Please provide more information on your shell-command to further assist you problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us an example of what you've tried and where it is failing.